# Debugger in pycharm is not working if add comments

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm

```
# If I add comment then debugging is not working
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(4 - i):
        print("# ", end=" ")
    print()
```

> If add a breakpoint on first for loop then it directly executes whole
> code. But If I remove the comment then it is working!

Comment: If you are setting a breakpoint on a comment line, it never gets executed.

Comment: No, it's on for loop and by default there is no option to add breakpoint on comment.

Comment: Does placing a breakpoint inside the first for loop work?

Comment: This is one of the cases where a screenshot helps